# Creating and running an Android wear app

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

Based on the Android docs (https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/wearables/apps/creating.html), is it recommended to follow this procedure even if my wear app has no **notifications** in it? My project basically consists of modules (common, mobile, and wear) which runs perfectly well whenever I run either the mobile or wear module on the according virtual emulator.

Thanks a bunch!

P.S. Could anybody link me to the Android Wear app on Google Play? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still follow the instruction set within the link you have referenced. 
Link to wear app on the playstore: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app

Comment: Ok, I followed the instructions, but yet my wear app only gets a notification instead of it being installed on the wear device when I run the mobile apk (where the wear apk is also embedded in), whereas the app gets installed on my mobile device. Here's my question in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266770/wearable-app-does-not-install-from-mobile-apk